# Activating the system menu

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a custom window with no title/caption bar.  I have added a system-menu icon/button to the custom menu bar.  Here is the code that handles the command from that button, where I attempt to access the system menu:

```
case ID_MENUBAR_SYS:
    HMENU  hSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE);
    TrackPopupMenu(hSysMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, 0, cyMenu, 0, hWnd, NULL);
```

The button works, and the system menu is displayed.  However, none of the menu items are active.  I just get a beep, signaling an invalid command.  Supposedly, `GetSystemMenu()` only returns a *copy*.  How do I get *access* to the actual system menu?

As a temporary measure, I have used `SendInput()` to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Though that works, implementation requires an ugly mess of code. Plus, it seems like too much of a brute-force approach.

On a side question, why does `TrackPopupMenu()` use screen coordinates, rather than window coordinates? Is there a flag that I need to set?

Comment: When you say the menu items are inactive, do you mean they're disabled/ghosted? Or can you select them? `TrackPopupMenu()` uses screen coordinates because it... just does. You can use `ClientToScreen()` to convert from client coords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu):

> **hWnd**
>
> A handle to the window that owns the shortcut menu. This window receives all messages from the menu. The window does not receive a WM_COMMAND message from the menu until the function returns. If you specify TPM_NONOTIFY in the uFlags parameter, the function does not send messages to the window identified by hWnd. However, you must still pass a window handle in hWnd. It can be any window handle from your application.

So when you click on the menu option, you did not process the message in `WM_COMMAND`. And you can handle the copy returned by [`GetSystemMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu) separately in `WM_COMMAND` like the following code:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if (wParam == SC_MINIMIZE)
    {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can also forward the message to `WM_SYSCOMMAND` for system default processing. You can refer to the following code:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, the documentation of [`TrackPopupMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu) states that the pop-up menu can be anywhere on the screen, so it is originally set up like this.

> Displays a shortcut menu at the specified location and tracks the selection of items on the menu. The shortcut menu can appear anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Zhu Song.  Forwarding the commands by `SendMessage()` seemed to be the best solution.  I didn't know that the commands were being sent to `WM_COMMAND`, rather than `WM_SYSCOMMAND`.